# Group by alphabetically all rows based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Stuck on this...
I need something like GROUP BY, but also affect grouping results for all other rows in column cat_name accordingly to id (prod_id in example).
Example table:

```
 +------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
 | cat_name         | cat_id | prod_id | prod_name   | prod_img     |
 +------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------
 | Foo Category     |     54 |     755 | product a   | prod_a_img_1 |
 | A Category       |     22 |     755 | product a   | prod_a_img_3 |
 | Bar Category     |     59 |     755 | product a   | prod_a_img_2 |
 | Category three   |     85 |     767 | product b   | prod_b_img_1 |
 +------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

What I want to have:

```
+------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| cat_name         | cat_id | prod_id | prod_name   | prod_img     |
+------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------
| A Category       |     54 |     755 | product a   | prod_a_img_1 |
| A Category       |     22 |     755 | product a   | prod_a_img_3 |
| A Category       |     59 |     755 | product a   | prod_a_img_2 |
| Category three   |     85 |     767 | product b   | prod_b_img_1 |
+------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Categories have unique ID, but I need select only first category in each row (alphabetically).

My full query:

```
select categories.name as cat_name,
   categories.slug as cat_uri,
   categories.term_id as cat_id,
   object_id,
   term_taxonomy_id,
   ID as prod_id,
   post_title as prod_name,
   img as prod_img
   from
   wp_posts,
   wp_term_relationships,
   (select term_id,
   name,
   slug
   from
   wp_terms group by name) as categories
   where post_type = "product" and
   object_id = ID and
   term_taxonomy_id = term_id
```

Comment: I think your expected result is first one and what you getting right now is second one. can you clarify

Comment: Does the following achieve what you want, when you add it to the end? Order by categories.name ASC

Comment: @Ameya Deshpande, no. I have some product(s) which are attached to many categories. And I want select only first category (alphabetically), in example - I want to select just " A Category" and omit other categories from this product (prod_id 755) - (" Foo Category", "Bar Category")

Comment: @TotalFault ok now got it

Comment: @Shauno_88  sure not. I think that I need to add another subquery and add group by cat_name there. But don't know how correctly to this :)

Comment: I'm surprised that MIN(cat_name) appears nowhere within your question

Comment: Use a correlated sub-query to get cat_name. Besides, your query includes several tables, but your example data is only for one table...???

Comment: @Strawberry, so I've tried to do subquery with min(cat_name) and group by cat_name asc. But this doesn't work because all categories for product are still selected.

Comment: @jarlh, this is result of queries. U're right, there are three tables (crazy wordpress issue :) but this is not important here)

Comment: @TotalFault show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking something like this:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT ti.cat_name 
        FROM yourTable ti 
        WHERE ti.prod_id = t.prod_id
        ORDER BY ti.cat_name
        LIMIT 1) As cat_name, 
    t.cat_id, 
    t.prod_id, 
    t.prod_name, 
    t.prod_img
FROM 
    yourTable t
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Oops, WHERE ti.prod_id = t.prod_id will be correct.